# Google Tag Manager for iOS getting FunctionCallMacro

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-tag-manager

I'm using [Google Tag Manager **v3**](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/). Every time I'm calling a custom function callback, I'm getting these warnings:

```
GoogleTagManager warning: FunctionCallMacro: expected additional_params to be a map.
```

Meanwhile, I'm using GTM inside a custom framework. From the main app I call the framework then I call to GTM.

This is how I configured GTM inside my adapter.
[image]

Below is the screenshot of the custom function.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the custom function setup in Google Tag Manager?

Comment: @EricBurley I updated question with screenshot

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, can you provide a screenshot of how you've configured the Google Tag Manager container to use the custom function.

Comment: @EricBurley I updated with new screenshot

Comment: Apologies for the confusion: I meant can you log into Google Tag Manager's web site, open the tag or macro that calls the custom tag/macro, and screenshot the website, so we can see what parameters are being passed?